# 3-state button behavior (default, pressed, disabled)

Tags: wpf, button, triggers

What's the idiomatic (and preferably easiest) way to implement a 3-state button where the states are:

- default
- pressing
- disabled

So far I have this:

```
<Button ToolTip="Back" FontWeight="Bold" Command="{Binding Path=Navigator.GoBackCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Navigator.CanGoBack}">
  <Viewbox Width="10">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CoolLeftArrow}"/>
  </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

Is it necessary to replace the control template to get such behavior or can it be gotten using triggers? Ideally I just want to specify 3 different resources and bind them to the relevant properties.

Edit: Updated name "pressed" state to "pressing" to avoid confusion with possible checkbox-like behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use a ToggleButton with [`IsThreeState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.isthreestate.aspx) set to `true`?

```
<ToggleButton IsThreeState="True">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TbCheckedContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TbUncheckedContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource TbNullContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

---

**UPDATE** I guess i haven't read your question carefully enough. You may of course do something similar to the above for a Button's `IsPressed` and `IsEnabled` properties:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPressedContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

---

You may however take a look into [VisualStates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc672805.aspx) and then into [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) to get an overview of how to visualize these states in a Button's ControlTemplate.

Comment: Yup, that's what the toggle is for.  You can also define a ControlTemplate for the toggle to represent the states in the way that you want them.

Comment: The perfect solution would of course be a ToggleButton ControlTemplate with appropriately defined VisualStates. See [ToggleButton Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468212.aspx) for an example of a ToggleButton ControlTemplate.

Comment: Doesn't this work like a checkbox then? I specifically need to have a button with one default look, another "user is pressing on button" look and a third "button is disabled" look. I don't need/want a checked/unchecked look because it should not work like a checkbox.

Comment: You might look into the ControlTemplate example in [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx). It shows how the VisualStates `Normal`, `MouseOver`, `Pressed` and `Disabled` are visualized.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I'll try out your answer soon! Thanks for your efforts.